# Bound on oscillation of product of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> For $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\to [-M,M]$, prove that $$\rm{Osc}_{fg}\leq M(\rm{Osc}_f+\rm{Osc}_g)$$

Where $$Osc_{f}(x_0)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}(\sup_{x\in B_\varepsilon(x_0)}f(x)-\inf_{x\in B_\varepsilon(x_0)}f(x))$$
is the oscillation of the function at $x_0$.

I realize that the maximum oscillation is when one function takes the values $M$ and $-M$ and the other takes twice the value $M$, which exactly gives equality. But I'm not sure how to generalize it for any values of $f$ and $g$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$${\rm osc}_f(a):=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\>\sup\nolimits_{x,y\in B_\epsilon(a)}|f(x)-f(y)|\ ,$$
which makes even sense when $f$ is vector-valued.

Now from
$$f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)=f(x)\bigl(g(x)-g(y)\bigr)+g(y)\bigl(f(x)-f(y)\bigr)\ ,$$
it follows that
$$\bigl|(fg)(x)-(fg)(y)\bigr|\leq M\bigl(|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|\bigr)\ ,$$
and this easily implies the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0, x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n, x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)$. First, note $fg(x)\leq \frac{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}{2}$. Second, we can prove 
$$
f^2(x)\leq M\max\left\{\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x),-\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x)\right\}
$$
and similarly for $g$. For convencience, let us denote
$$
M_{f,\varepsilon}:=\max\left\{\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x),-\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x)\right\}\\
M_{g,\varepsilon}:=\max\left\{\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}g(x),-\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}g(x)\right\}\\
m_{f,\varepsilon}:=\min\left\{-\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x),\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x)\right\}\\
m_{g,\varepsilon}:=\min\left\{-\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}g(x),\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}g(x)\right\}
$$
Hence, for all $x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)$,
$$
fg(x)\leq \frac{M}{2}\left(M_{f,\varepsilon}+M_{g,\varepsilon}\right)
$$
which implies
$$
\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}fg(x)\leq \frac{M}{2}\left(M_{f,\varepsilon}+M_{g,\varepsilon}\right)
$$
Similarly, we can show 
$$
\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}fg(x)\geq \frac{M}{2}\left(m_{f,\varepsilon}+m_{g,\varepsilon}\right)
$$
Hence, we deduce
$$
\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}fg(x)-\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}fg(x) \leq  \frac{M}{2}\left(M_{f,\varepsilon}-m_{f,\varepsilon}+M_{g,\varepsilon}-m_{g,\varepsilon}\right)
$$
where the RHS equals 
$$
\frac{M}{2}\left(\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x)-\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}f(x)+\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}g(x)-\inf_{x\in B(x_0,\varepsilon)}g(x)\right)
$$
Since this is true for all $\varepsilon>0$, taking limits we deduce 
$$
Osc_{fg}(x_0)\leq \frac{M}{2}(Osc_{f}(x_0)+Osc_{g}(x_0))
$$